# PHP str_replace is not working with unicode variable content

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match-all

I am working in PHP and I am trying to use str_replace in a text with unicode characters.

If I replace with this code, this works fine:

```
$message = str_replace($unicode_char, "\u{1F44B}", $message); 
echo $message;
```

This displays in the screen: [image]

But if I replace with this code, this works bad:

```
$myvar = "\u{1F44B}";
$message = str_replace($unicode_char, $myvar, $message); 
echo $message;
```

This displays in the screen: [image]

My full code is this:

```
function convertAll() {
      $message = "\\U0001F44B Hi! welcome! \\U0001F603";
      preg_match_all("(\\\\U[a-fA-F0-9]{8})", $message, $groups);
      if (!empty($groups)) {
        
        $groups = $groups[0];
        
        foreach ($groups as $g) {
            $unicode_char = strval($g);
            $unicoded = str_replace('\U000', '\u{', $unicode_char).'}';
            echo $unicoded."\n";
            $message = str_replace($unicode_char, "\u{1F44B}", $message); 
        }
        //$message = "\u{1F44B}".$message."\u{1F603}";
      }
      return($message);
  }
```

Do you know a better script to do it?
A lot of thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you used double quotes when you assigned `$myvar`? The result you show would happen if you used single quotes.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$unicoded`? You never use it.

Comment: Your code works with `$myvar` for me: https://ideone.com/MLWGLO

Comment: Do you want to do `str_replace($unicode_char, $unicoded, $message)`? `$unicoded` isn't a Unicode character, it's a string beginning with literal `\u{`.